# Java is it possible to use a string to access a field in another class?

Tags: java

if I have a class `Base` with this in it:

```
public static Tab thisTab = new TabClass(5200, "thisItem");
public final static Item thisItem = new SomeClass(par1, par2);
```

and in the `TabClass` class I want to be able to access some information from `thisItem`, but without `TabClass` knowing the name of `thisItem`

```
public TabClass(int par1, String par2) {
    int num;
    Base.(Here is where i need the item that par2 is the name of).ID = num;
}
```

How would I somehow get the field that `par2` represents to actually be usable when looking for the value of ID?

Comment: This can be done with reflection but .. *don't do this*. Instead, design the API in such a way that either the static type interface is used or it provides access via an exposed (name->valueOfField) lookup method: e.g. `Item getItemByName(String name)`.

Answer (score 0):

try java reflection method..

```
Item item = new Item();
Field field = Item.class.getDeclaredField(par2);
field.set(item, new Item(234));
```

your Item class have constructor

```
public Item(int ID){
    this.ID = ID;
}
```

Comment: It would be worth mentioning in your answer that this is a terrible idea.